# How can I draw this complex shape using iOS Quartz 2D drawing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-2d

I know how to draw simple shapes - rectangles, ellipses and lines etc. using iOS Quartz 2D drawing.

Just now I'm trying to draw a relatively complex shape though, the tail of a musical quaver:

[image: Quaver]

Can anybody suggest a good way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you design the quaver in a graphics program like [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/), export as an SVG, and then render using [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit)? From a development level, it would be much easier to maintain something that you can visually update, rather than trying to draw a shape with code.

Answer (score 3):

What I have learned from my designers is, that you start with a simple form and then extend and change it in single, small steps. Sometime later you arrive at the complex form. So, like answered by @Duncan C building a path. Now I know that is quite tedious. One alternative not mentioned here is PaintCode, an app that produces Cocoa code from your drawing. It is called [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com) and should do what you want. Btw I am not affiliated with the makers of PaintCode!

Answer (score 2):

You could draw that as a filled UIBezierPath (which is a UIKit wrapper on a CGPath).

You'd open a path, draw a sequence of straight lines and cubic or quadratic bezier curves, then close the path. Then you'd draw it as a filled path.

Once you have the path created, you could draw it with a single call.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of alternatives, as Duncan seems to have answered this.

One option would be to dynamically scale a high resolution image.

There is one caveat with this approach: you should not scale anything below 1/2 of the original size, otherwise the interpolation tends to glitch.

So you would need to store image at say 64x64, 128x128, 256x256 etc

You could pack all of these into a single 256x512, and this is what a lot of games do.

Another option is to render a quaver unicode character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/266a/index.htm

Comment: I never realised there were unicode characters for musical entities - thanks for that!